# How to redirect back to previous page in laravel 8 after Login

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a blog where users can only comment after being logged in.

**The Problem**

After login, the page is redirected to the home page.

`blog_details.blade`

'''

```
@if(!Auth::check())
    <h3 class="news-details__title">Leave a reply</h3>

    <a class="thm-btn sidebar__tags-btn" href="{{route('login')}}">
        You must be logged in to post a comment.</a>

@else
<div id="app">
<div class="comment-one">
    <h3 class="comment-one__title">Comments</h3>
    <div class="comment-one__single">
        <div class="comment-one__image">
            <img src="assets/images/blog/comment-1-2.png" alt="">
        </div>

            <get-comments :userid="{{Auth::user()->id}}" :blogid="{{$blog->id}}"></get-comments>


    </div>
</div>


<div class="comment-form">
    <h3 class="comment-form__title">Leave a Comment</h3>
    <form action="#" class="comment-one__form contact-form-validated"
        novalidate="novalidate">

            <add-comment :userid="{{Auth::user()->id}}" :blogid="{{$blog->id}}"></add-comment>



    </form>
</div>
</div>
    @endif
```

'''

**Question**

What should do to be redirected back to the blog details page?

** I have tried**

`Login Controller`

```
 use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
   // protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return url()->previous();
    }
```

Thank you for the assist

EDIT
**Custom Login Controller**
Shows the custom login.
I have included my custom login controller, the 'index' method returns the login form and the 'customLogin' checks user table and validates, How do I redirect back to the previous method?

```
<?php

class CustomAuthController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }


    public function customLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'phone_number' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('phone_number', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->intended('/')
                        ->withSuccess('Signed in');
        }

        return redirect("login")->withSuccess('Login details are not valid');
    }


}
```

Comment: if they are clicking a login link you would need to, in the action handling returning the login form, save what the previous page was in the session then after login redirect to this page ... you could set the 'intended' url to do this since the redirect is using `redirect()->intended(...)` ... currently, when `redirectTo` is called at that point the previous page is the login form so redirecting there would cause the `guest` middleware to redirect the user away to the homepage

Comment: I am finding it hard to follow, kindly explain more

Comment: what part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hello, let us start with saving the previous page in a session. I have edited with a snippet of my custom login controller.